# jQuery: show different text with different buttons

Tags: jquery, button, text, show

I first tried this code at it works.

```
$(function(){
    $('#k1').click(function(){
        $('#textbox').empty();
        $('#textbox').prepend('hello');
    });
    $('#k2').click(function(){
        $('#textbox').empty();
        $('#textbox').prepend('hola');
    });
    $('#k3').click(function(){
        $('#textbox').empty();
        $('#textbox').prepend('bonjour');
    });
});
```

However, I must only have ONE event handler, and I'm pretty sure the code above doesn't count as one. What I need to have is three different buttons: each button showing its own text, for example:
button1: hello
button2: hola
button3: bonjour

Any tips?

Comment: Is there HTML that goes with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<input type="text" />
<button>Hola</button>
<button>Hello</button>
<button>Bonjour</button>

$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("input").val($(this).text());
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/Wkd3D/)**

Within your click handler, `$(this)` will refer to the element which was clicked to trigger the event, so you can just grab it's text or value or store some arbitrary text on it as a data attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom **data-* attribute** to store text.

Example

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" />
<button data-display-text="Hola">k1</button>
<button data-display-text="Hello">k2</button>
<button data-display-text="Bobjour">k3</button>
```

*JavaScript*

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
    $("input").val($(this).data('display-text'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Xjm2V/)

**OR**

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
$('#k1, #k2, #k3').click(function(){
    $('#textbox').empty();
    if($(this)is('#k1,'))
        $('#textbox').prepend('hello');
    if($(this)is('#k2,'))
        $('#textbox').prepend('hola');
    if($(this)is('#k3,'))
        $('#textbox').prepend('bonjour');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/pEAb5/)

First give you buttons a common class (For example, `k-button`) just so it's cleaner than enumerating all the IDs.

Then you can do something like:

```
var helloKeyVal = {"k1":"hello","k2":"hola","k3":"bonjour"}

$(".k-button").click(function(){
  $("#textbox").prepend(helloKeyVal[this.id]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I added $('#textbox').empty(); to empty the textbox and then the code worked just as I wanted.